# Same phone number with multiple extensions always get registered in the call log with one single user

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, phone-app, call-history

I'm using the default factory Dialer, Call Log, Contacts app (all those options are running under the same app) on LG L90 running Lollipop 5.0.2.

I created multiple users with the same phone number but then I added a comma (,) and then for each user used a different extension.

For example:

- John Doe 1 555 555-5555, 2000
- Mary Jane 1 555 555-5555, 2001
- Jane Roe 1 555 555-5555, 2002

The problem is that when I receive a call from the office the call always gets registered with the first user that I created with the number. For example, I made a call to Jane Roe but that call got registered as John Doe or I received a call from Mary Jane but the name on display was John Doe. With that I can not know who calls me from the office.

- If I try to re-dial that last number it is always John Doe that shows up and then the dialer dials 1 555 555-5555, 2000 instead of 1 555 555-5555, 2001.
- If I delete John Doe then Mary Jane (the second user that was created) is the account that get always registered in the call log.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are these extensions transmitted in CallerIDs?

Comment: Alex, as far as I know, no, there is no DID involved. I want to add that the same thing happens, not only receiving calls but also dialing numbers. For example if I dial for Jane Roe, John Doe gets registered as the dialed number. My previous "smartphone" was a blackberry and I was able to dial the same number with different extensions and get the activity properly registered in the call log.

Comment: Have you tried a different separator, e.g. another `-`? Usually, the comma means inserting a small pause when dialling – but I don't know how Android deals with that in phone numbers.